# Poor Flex tap response on iOS

Tags: ios, apache-flex, adobe, touch

We have several item renderers in our app, and we've noticed that the responsiveness of these UI elements to taps can vary greatly.

Example:

```
    private function setupClickHandling():void
    {
        //this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, clickHandler);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
    }

    protected function clickHandler(e:Object):void
    {
        var event:ItemClickEvent = 
                        new ItemClickEvent(ItemClickEvent.ITEM_CLICK, true);
        event.item = data;
        event.index = itemIndex;
        dispatchEvent(event);
    }
```

When using MouseEvent.CLICK, sometimes a tap will not register as an actual click, **even though** the control spends a bit of time in the "down" state. This is most frustrating because the user believes that the control has been triggered, but nothing happens other than the grey background flash because a click event is not fired.

When using TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, taps become **too** responsive, and sometimes the list item will get triggered while the list is being drag scrolled. I would think that the tap interface would register a tap no matter how brief the duration as long as the centerpoint does not move appreciably, and that as soon as enough movement is detected the tap will not be registered. Instead, what appears to happen is the tap event is registered on the down portion of the event, not the up.

So, is there a way to either increase the sensitivity of Click, or decrease the sensitivity of Tap?

Or ideally, always register a tap as an actual tap?

Comment: Are your graphics too complex?  I had a lot of problems with this until I simplified the graphics significantly.

Comment: Try adding e.updateAfterEvent to the clickhandler. although it sounds as if you need to optimize your renderers.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com The one screen is just a simple s:List using a mobile-optimized IconItemRenderer and two buttons in the action bar.

Comment: @Eran From my reading, updateAfterEvent only causes the engine to render immediately after the event instead of waiting for the next frame. I don't see how that will fix an event not firing at all as in the MouseEvent.CLICK issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can roll your own tap gesture. Here is how I did it..

```
public function BaseItemRenderer()
    {
        super();
        Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
        this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin);
        this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, onTouchMove);
        this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd);
    }

    protected var touching:Boolean;
    protected var touchStartTime:int;
    protected var touchStartX:Number;
    protected var touchStartY:Number;

    private function onTouchBegin(e:TouchEvent):void
    {
        trace("onTouchBegin");
        touching = true;
        touchStartTime = getTimer();
        touchStartX = e.stageX;
        touchStartY = e.stageY;
    }

    private function onTouchMove(e:TouchEvent):void
    {
        //
    }

    protected static const TAP_MIN_DURATION:int = 0;
    protected static const TAP_MAX_DURATION:int = 1000;
    protected static const TAP_MIN_DISTANCE:Number = 0;
    protected static const TAP_MAX_DISTANCE:Number = 40;

    private function onTouchEnd(e:TouchEvent):void
    {

        if(touching)
        {
            touching = false;
            var duration:int = getTimer()-touchStartTime;
            var distanceX:Number = e.stageX - touchStartX;
            var distanceY:Number = e.stageY - touchStartY;
            var distance:Number = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(distanceX, 2) + Math.pow(distanceY, 2));
            trace("onTouchEnd duration:" + duration + " distance:" + distance);

            if(duration >= TAP_MIN_DURATION &&
                duration <= TAP_MAX_DURATION &&
                distance >= TAP_MIN_DISTANCE &&
                distance <= TAP_MAX_DISTANCE)
            {
                onTap(e.target);
            }
        }

    }
```